# Add user to meeting automatically

Tags: exchange-2010, skype-for-business-2016

We use Exchange 2010. We have several meeting rooms and each room has a computer for remote SFB users. Computer runs by special AD user (e.g. meetingroom1_comp for meetingroom1). Problem is when meeting occurs, that special user does not join meeting by default. We have to send a link to meeting or include that user in participants list beforehand. Is there a way to automate that proccess so user joins conference to corresponding meeting room?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a transport rule and enable **`Automatically Accept Meeting`** in Outlook for this special AD user, the following similar thread is for your reference: **[Add user to meeting automatically](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2306021-add-user-to-meeting-automatically?page=1#entry-9093444)**

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved through transport rule, which blind carbon copies all calendaring-type messages from room mailbox to computer mailbox.

Comment: I'm glad that your problem has been fixed, and you could mark the solution as the best answer to help others who have the same problem.
Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, is there any update?